# Links work in IE...but not in firefox and safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari

i'm taken over a website and I'm having issues with a template. For some reason most of the hyperlinks on the page won't render in Firefox or Safari but work fine in IE...

This is the page in question: http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/your_services/leisure_services/leisure_centres/cheslyn_hay_leisure_centre1.aspx

Code for page template is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<head runat="server">
<title>South Staffordshire Council - <imm:PageProps type="title" runat="server" id="AutoId1"><%--><--%></imm:PageProps></title>
<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


<immCore:Null><%--><!--<--%></immCore:Null>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10,chrome=1">
<immCore:Null><%-->--><--%></immCore:Null>

<link title="Alternate Page" href="ILINK|0,|" rel="alternate"/>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<link href="css/bs/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<link href="css/system/southstaffs2013.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="css/bs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="ratingSelector.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive_stylesheets/skeleton.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive_stylesheets/stylesheets/layout.css">



<!-- ie8 support -->
<script src="css/bs/js/respond.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<style>
div.horizontal
{
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:135px;
width:1100px;
height:40px;
}
div.horizontal ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div.horizontal li
{
float:left;
}
div.horizontal a
{
display:block;
width:120px;
height:40px;
}
div.horizontal a:link,div.horizontal a:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#97ca61;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
div.horizontal a:hover,div.horizontal a:active
{
background-color:#22772d;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

<div class="container" id="content">

<div id="globalnavRS"> 
  <immCore:ListMenu LinksPage="3450" runat="server" id="AutoId4">
  <headertemplate>
  </headertemplate>
  <itemtemplate>
  <a href="<%# Container.Link %>" title="<%# Container.Title %>"><%# Container.Title %></a> 
  </itemtemplate>
  <separatortemplate>
  &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
  </separatortemplate>
  <%-->Global&nbsp;|&nbsp;Menu&nbsp;|&nbsp;Here<--%>
  </immCore:ListMenu>
</div>

<div id="searchbar"> <custom:searchbar runat="server" id="Auto2332Id31"> </custom:searchbar> 

 </div>
<div id="mastheadRS"></div>
<div id="headerr">
 <a href="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk">
 <img alt="header" src="images/newsite/ssdclogo.gif"/>
</a>
</div>

<div id="ealert"> <a href="https://public.govdelivery.com/accounts/UKSSTAFFS/subscriber/new"><img alt="South Staffordshire e-alerts" src="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/images/ealert_box.gif" /></a>
</div> 


<div class="horizontal">
<ul>
<li><a href="ILINK|22332,|">Centre Home</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|19817,|">Prices</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|13380,|">Swimming</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|13376,|">Fitness Suite</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|13375,|">Exercise Classes</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|13374,|">Dry Sports & Courses</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|19505,|">3g Astro Pitch</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|13322,|"> </a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<br/>


<imm:area name="main" runat="server" id="AutoId14"> Test Content
<p>Some content will go here and look like this. </p>
</imm:area>   


<immCore:Null><%--><!--<--%></immCore:Null>


<div id="ratethispage">
                                    <span class="text">Rate this page</span>
<br />
<span class="items"><a rel="nofollow,noindex" class="rating_item" href="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/Default.aspx?page=17786&amp;PageRate=<% =Immediacy.Web.ImmHttpContext.Current.ContentPage.ID %>&amp;Rating=1"><img src="star_off.gif" alt="Rate this page - 1 / 5" width="18" height="17" border="0" /></a><a rel="nofollow,noindex" class="rating_item" href="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/Default.aspx?page=17786&amp;PageRate=<% =Immediacy.Web.ImmHttpContext.Current.ContentPage.ID %>&amp;Rating=2"><img src="star_off.gif" alt="Rate this page - 2 / 5" width="18" height="17" border="0" /></a><a rel="nofollow,noindex" class="rating_item" href="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/Default.aspx?page=17786&amp;PageRate=<% =Immediacy.Web.ImmHttpContext.Current.ContentPage.ID %>&amp;Rating=3"><img src="star_off.gif" alt="Rate this page - 3 / 5" width="18" height="17" border="0" /></a><a rel="nofollow,noindex" class="rating_item" href="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/Default.aspx?page=17786&amp;PageRate=<% =Immediacy.Web.ImmHttpContext.Current.ContentPage.ID %>&amp;Rating=4"><img src="star_off.gif" alt="Rate this page - 4 / 5" width="18" height="17" border="0" /></a><a rel="nofollow,noindex" class="rating_item" href="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/Default.aspx?page=17786&amp;PageRate=<% =Immediacy.Web.ImmHttpContext.Current.ContentPage.ID %>&amp;Rating=5"><img src="star_off.gif" alt="Rate this page - 5 / 5" width="18" height="17" border="0" /></a></span></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                                    var rating = new ratingSelector("ratethispage","Rate this page","-1","3.02","386");//-->
                                </script>
<noscript></noscript>

<br />                  

<footer>
<div id="footerRSWide">
<custom:browseservices2013 runat="server" id="Auto27868763"> </custom:browseservices2013>


<div style="text-align: center">

<a href="http://southstaffordshire.thegoodlife.uk.net/"><img src="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/images/newsite/goodlifewebsite.gif" alt="South Staffordshire Goodlife Website" width="136px" Height="25px" /></a>

<a href="http://www.staffordshireprepared.gov.uk/Home.aspx"><img src="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/images/newsite/staffsprep.gif" alt="Staffordshire Prepared website" /></a>
<a href="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/Home.aspx"><img src="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/images/newsite/i54bw.gif" alt="i54 information website" /></a>

<a href="http://www.direct.gov.uk"><img src="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/images/newsite/directgov2.gif" alt="DirectGov" /></a>

<br/><br/>

<a style="color: #ffffff; " href="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/Default.aspx?page=313">accreditations</a> |  South Staffordshire Council 2012 | <a style="color: #ffffff; " href="http://www.sstaffs.gov.uk/Default.aspx?page=33">Privacy policy and Cookies</a> 



</div>


<script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en',
    gaTrack: true,
    gaId: 'UA-6726888-1',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
  }, 'google_translate_element1');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>


</footer>
<immCore:Null><%-->--><--%></immCore:Null>

<!-- content -->
</div>
</div><!-- container -->



</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-6726888-1");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
</script>





</body>
</html>
```

Any advise would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

These aren't a URL at all, hyperlinks must contain URL or an Anchor.

```
<li><a href="ILINK|22332,|">Centre Home</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|19817,|">Prices</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|13380,|">Swimming</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|13376,|">Fitness Suite</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|13375,|">Exercise Classes</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|13374,|">Dry Sports & Courses</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|19505,|">3g Astro Pitch</a></li>
<li><a href="ILINK|13322,|"> </a></li>ILINK|22332,|"
```

URLs should be in format like this (*path/filename.fileExtension*)

e.g. links tags:

```
<li><a href="home.html">Centre Home</a></li>
```

or

```
<li><a href="http://www.yousite.com/home.html">Centre Home</a></li>
```

IE is usually ignoring such errors, unlike the other browsers.

*Suggestions:*

1. Avoid using special characters in the folder/files such as (|) and
   (,). and use (_) or (-) in replace of spaces.
2. Also don't forget about the case sensitive of URLs (Follow exact
   url value, Capital letters or 'Upper Case' in file name must remain
   Capital, do the same with small letters)

Comment: The links you've highlighted seem to work within the CMS we use (Immediacy/ Alterian). Trouble is it isn't just those links that don't work. Normal URL style links don't work either, either linked from text or from images.

I think its to do with the CSS behind the template rather than the page template itself, I can post that if its of any interest?